# Accessing portal URL in Javascript in Plone

Tags: plone

Does Plone (4) expose the portal URL to Javascript somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it is exposed by `plone_javascript_variables` view in CMFPlone

https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/browser/jsvariables.py

Comment: portal_url is the variable name to be specific.